# using xjc with ant

Tags: java, jaxb, xjc

I am trying to use xjc compiler from ant. Builds successfully but nothing gets generated.
My ant script is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project name="AutomateWithAnt" basedir=".">
    <property file="build.properties"/>

    <path id="compile.classpath">
    <fileset dir="${lib.includes}" includes="*.jar"></fileset>
    </path>

    <target name="init" description="create java class">
    </target>   
    <taskdef name="xjc" classname="com.sun.tools.xjc.XJCTask" classpathref="compile.classpath"/>

    <!-- Generates the source code from the test.xsd schema using jaxb -->
    <target name="option-generate" description="Generates the source code" depends="init">      
        <xjc schema="test.xsd" destdir="${generated-src.dir}" package="${generated-src.dir}">
            <arg value="-Xcommons-lang" />
            <arg value="-Xcommons-lang:ToStringStyle=SHORT_PREFIX_STYLE" />
            <produces dir="${generated-src.dir}" includes="**/*.java" />
        </xjc>
    </target>
</project>
```

my build.properties is:

```
lib.includes=lib/
generated-src.dir=/
```

I am using java 1.6 and I have used jaxb-sjc.jar.

Comment: Are you sure your `xjc` task is being invoked? Add `<echo>` to your task. Or you invoke your ant as `ant xjc`?

Comment: Yeah you were right, its not being called. Can you please tell me whats I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've defined 2 Ant targets (`init` and `option-generate`), but neither of them will be invoked unless you specify which one to run.

You either need to specify it on the command line, e.g.

```
ant option-generate
```

or add a default target to the `<project>` element, e.g.

```
<project name="AutomateWithAnt" basedir="." default="option-generate">
```

Incidentally, your `init` target is empty, and therefore pointless.